# How Geomesa overcome HBase hotspotting problem for spatial indexes

Tags: hbase, geomesa

How Geomesa solves the hotspotting problem for Spatial and Spatio-temporal data which is a common problem in space-filling curve?

I read below documents but not able to understand what is Striping? and How it helps.

http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/march/article3.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article is fairly out of date. Currently, GeoMesa mitigates hot-spotting through prepending a shard prefix to each row, which ensures that some data will be spread out among different table regions. See [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/index_config.html#configuring-z-index-shards) and [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/index_config.html#configuring-attribute-index-shards) for details on configuring shards.

If you know your data distribution up front, GeoMesa supports custom [pre-splitting](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/index_config.html#configuring-index-splits) of index tables, which can be used to completely eliminate hot spots.

In all cases, hot-spotting is further mitigated by automatic table splitting in [HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#disable.splitting) or [Accumulo](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.9/accumulo_user_manual.html#_splitting). Regions will split based on size, so areas of dense features will automatically be split up once they hit the threshold.

Comment: How appending a shard prefix works? Let's suppose I initialized the Geomesa with whole OSM (Open Street Map) data with 10 Shards (a random number) but most of the BBOX read request I received belongs to one city like New York. Will I get hot spotting issue?

Comment: If you use 10 shards, then your query will hit at least 10 regions, so hot-spotting should be minimized.